# Modify Custom Field in Media Library using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, media-library, media-modal

I've added a custom field into my media attachments:

```
function set_image_data( $form_fields, $post ) {

    $form_fields['text_color'] = array(
        'label' => 'Text Color',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_color', true )
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'set_image_data', 10, 2 );
```

Which is fine and dandy, but now I'd like to add Colorpicker ( I understand it is deprecated ) to the above field. Unfortunately, `jQuery` doesn't seem to have an effect as the Media Library is dynamic. I've tried handlers but I can't seem to catch the input to even place a generic `val()` into it.

I believe once I understand how to modify the field I should be able to grasp then how to attach Colorpicker to the field.

How can I use JS or jQuery to modify the field above on an attachment to attachment basis in the Media Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it (which is probably evil) is to select the control by adding a block of javascript using the `tr` field of `$form_fields`:

```
function set_image_data( $form_fields, $post ) {

    $form_fields['text_color'] = array(
        'label' => 'Text Color',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_color', true )
    );
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('[name$="[text_color]"]').myColorPicker();
    </script>
    <?php
    $text_color_js = ob_get_clean();
    $form_fields['text_color_js'] = array(
        'tr' => $text_color_js, // Adds free-form stuff to table.
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'set_image_data', 10, 2 );
```

The javascript is using a customized version of `wpColorPicker` that overrides the `close` to trigger a `change` event (needed since the hidden `text_color` field never gets/loses focus so doesn't do it itself):

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function () {
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            // Extend wpColorPicker to trigger change on close.
            $.widget('custom.myColorPicker', $.wp.wpColorPicker, {
                close: function () {
                    this._super();
                    if (this.initialValue !== this.element.val()) {
                        this.element.change();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

        <?php
}, 50 );
```

You could optionally wrap the above in a conditional so that it only includes the script on upload but it may not fire in some cases.

```
if ( get_current_screen()->base == 'upload' ) {}
```

Then there's standard stuff to load `wp-color-picker` and save the data:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if ( get_current_screen()->base == 'upload' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
    }
});
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', function ( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( isset( $attachment['text_color'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_text_color', $attachment['text_color'] );
    }
    return $post;
}, 10, 2 );
```

**Update**

This usage threw up a bug in `wpColorPicker` (see trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32856) in that if the color picker is left open and the Attachment Details modal is closed, an exception is thrown which puts things into a funny state. The workaround is not to call `this._super();` in the (very conveniently overridden) close but to replicate the code instead, with the fix:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function () {

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            // Extend wpColorPicker to trigger change on close.
            $.widget('custom.myColorPicker', $.wp.wpColorPicker, {
                close: function () {
                    this.element.hide();
                    if ( this.element.iris( 'instance' ) ) {
                        this.element.iris( 'toggle' );
                    }
                    this.button.addClass( 'hidden' );
                    this.toggler.removeClass( 'wp-picker-open' );
                    $( 'body' ).off( 'click.wpcolorpicker', this.close );
                    if (this.initialValue !== this.element.val()) {
                        this.element.change();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php

}, 50 );
```

Comment: Did you get a working demo? I keep getting an error like jQuery isn't included on the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter for the jquery snippet. `jQuery(...).myColorPicker is not a function` to be precise.

Comment: Yes, had a working demo, I suppose try putting the jquery snippet in a ready clause (will update answer) - but anyway I'm getting a strange "cannot call methods on iris prior to initialization" bug occasionally so answer seems doubtful...

Comment: I'm messing around with it as your code is definitely helpful, gives me something to work with. It may ( or may not ) be easier to work with the `'input' => 'html',` parameter to the array, pass the entire input markup and script into it most likely. Then you can easily ( `$form_fields['text_color']['html']  = "<script>etc."`

Comment: I see, it was the conditional in the `admin_print_footer_scripts` that was killing me. I'm running this both in a post type and on a `wp_editor()` in a metabox if that makes a difference. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Oh good, I see, feel free to edit the answer - I'll take out the ready clause stuff (which didn't make sense anyway). I'm still occasionally getting that "iris" bug, odd one, though it may be a jquery-ui thing...

Comment: where / how are you producing the error? I don't have anything in console or debug regarding it. I've edited your question to remove the conditional so that it works in as many cases as possible and the user can decide if they want to narrow it down.

Comment: Good stuff, ta. Re the "iris" bug it's the worst sort, not (so far) consistently reproducible so probably some timing issue (and probably nothing to do with this!)...

Comment: I tracked down the "iris" bug (which was after all reproducible) and opened a ticket for it on trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32856, I'll update the answer with the workaround...