# How to add a custom field to the media screen (image/gallery)?

Tags: uploads, media

I’m trying to add a custom field to image and gallery edit screen.

I’m aware there are similar questions here, although answers either don’t work with the current version or they add field only to **upload** screen while I need a field to be visible in all **edit** screens (see below).

For this, I believe, you’ll have to mess with *backbone.js* as `attachment_fields_to_edit` only adds to upload screen.

### Adding field with attachment_fields_to_edit

[image]

↑ This is upload image screeen. Here **Style** is added with `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter, and my_field is added with ACF plugin.

### But they are missing in edit screen in the post

[image]

↑ Click edit on the actual post

[image]

↑ No style & my_field fields!

### The question

How to add fields to still have them on the edit screen? Ideally answer will include adding fields to gallery edit screen if it’s a similar process

This question is really important for me so **I’ll be adding a 100 rep** bounty when it’s available.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to implement [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193096/7355)?

Comment: Does it work on the edit screen in the post? Because I’ve tried many answers from here and none with ```attachment_fields_to_edit``` worked.

Comment: What are the custom fields, *Style* & *my_field* used for? Should anything be added to the markup when the image is inserted into the editor based on these values? 

It seems that the settings in the *Image Details* modal are intended to be pulled from the markup of the image being edited and **not** from the attachment post itself. 

For example, set the caption to an image using the *Add Media > Attachment Details > Caption* field then click *Insert into post*. Now, edit the inserted image by hovering over it and clicking the pencil button. change the caption and click update.

Comment: Next, go back to the Media Library and look at the image's settings. Notice that the caption field has *not* been updated. 

This disconnect between the Image Details Modal and the Attachment Details settings presents a usability issue. Although it does seem possible to do what you're after here, it may not be a good idea to go through with it.

Comment: @DaveRomsey those are just placeholders — must have been clearer — but it can be used, for example, for providing author copyright for an image. Although I understand your concern, I think it will work because image in the post 99.9% won’t be reused in other places.

Comment: So as @DaveRomsey points out, the first screen on the edit image modal doesn't save the fields (caption/ alt text) to the original which is good in that it allows override for each case. So first I need to verify with you that the acf field created is not showing up on the attachment post edit page? It does for me. So if you really need to edit the custom fields, you can always do a search for the image in the Media Library and just edit the attachment there.

Comment: Now I'd also like to ask what @DaveRomsey has asked you. How exactly are you utilizing these fields? How are they being used both in the backend and frontend? It requires some work to get the edit modal to work but it should be entirely possible since we can hook into the image save action, but let's see how exactly are you using these fields? Why is it necessary to edit on the post?

Comment: @TurtleTread one of use cases for image is to add a field like Source (e.g. for the magazine). You would like to quickly change in-place rather than finding in Media Library and change there. For a gallery example is gallery / slider (so you either show it as a multicolumn gallery or as a slider / swiper). The idea is that it's in-place change that may not be reflected on actual post page.

Comment: I think basically the solution is just to hook into the modal save action and save the new fields as post_meta and update these particular custom fields through a custom ajax action.

Comment: @TurtleTread yes, but first you have to add them to the modal :) As I mentioned they don't show on the edit screen.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working code (working fine for me), did you tried this? Just add to theme 'functions.php' and change the custom field names as needed.

```
//function to add custom media field
function custom_media_add_media_custom_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_media_style', true );

    $form_fields['custom_media_style'] = array(
        'value' => $field_value ? $field_value : '',
        'label' => __( 'Style' ),
        'helps' => __( 'Enter your style' ),
        'input'  => 'textarea'
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'custom_media_add_media_custom_field', null, 2 );

//save your custom media field
function custom_media_save_attachment( $attachment_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][ $attachment_id ]['custom_media_style'] ) ) {
        $custom_media_style = $_REQUEST['attachments'][ $attachment_id ]['custom_media_style'];
        update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'custom_media_style', $custom_media_style );

    }
}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'custom_media_save_attachment' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my my own personal implementations of this functionality (without ACF), this is how I was able to achieve it using a combination of `attachment_fields_to_edit` and `attachment_fields_to_save`. View [GIST](https://gist.github.com/jaredrethman/68090e4cdfe82ec1cb61ba1d8d3fa6e7)

Usage:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'thumbnail_meta' );

function thumbnail_meta(){
  Thumbnail_Meta::create( [
            'html_thumbnail_meta_id'          => [
              'label' => __( '<strong>Featured Settings:</strong>' ),
              'input' => 'html'
            ],
            'checkbox_thumbnail_meta_id'        => [
              'label' => __( 'Checkbox?' ),
              'input' => 'checkbox'
            ],
            'url_thumbnail_meta_id'      => [
              'label' => __( 'Link:' ),
              'type'  => 'url',
            ],
            'select_thumbnail_meta_id' => [
              'label'   => __( 'Display' ),
              'input'   => 'select',
              'options' => [
                'none'   => '-- None --',
                'top'    => 'Content Top',
                'right'  => 'Content Right',
                'left'   => 'Content Left',
                'bottom' => 'Content bottom'
              ]
            ]
          ] );
  }
```

However - can't say for sure what the issue is without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for adding photographer name and url  in media editing screen.

```
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['be-photographer-name'] = array(
        'label' => 'Photographer Name',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_name', true ),
        'helps' => 'If provided, photo credit will be displayed',
    );

    $form_fields['be-photographer-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Photographer URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'If provided, photographer name will link here',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Save values of Photographer Name and URL in media uploader
 *
 * @param $post array, the post data for database
 * @param $attachment array, attachment fields from $_POST form
 * @return $post array, modified post data
 */

function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_name', $attachment['be-photographer-name'] );

    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_url', $attachment['be-photographer-url'] );

    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'be_attachment_field_credit_save', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup window You're trying to work with is rendered with js template inside **wp-includes/media-template.php**. Search for **tmpl-image-details**.

And yes, all we can do is to overwrite this template in our theme or plugin.
This might be the way You're looking for:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/268157/97253

Now I'm in progress of saving the field data and showing it then on frontend. Hopefully, I'll edit this post when finish that.